# Where best to create company wide groups in OFBiz?

Tags: erp, ofbiz

I am trying to create branches of a company (and then hopefully teams within branches) in Ofbiz. I had a look at the HR app, and whilst it does list a company and some departments and other stuff in the main view, I haven't been able to find a way to modify this org tree to remove or add to it. The only thing I can think off is to delete/modify this information in the DB, but I'd rather not resort to such tinkering (if it is indeed actually possible to do it this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with Relationsships in the Partymanager application.
(See `https://localhost:8443/partymgr/control/EditPartyRelationships?partyId=Company` if you're running a local default installation)

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten I had asked this question and already found the solution to it.